# How to Remove ACCES BACKGROUND LOCATION IN FLUTTER APP REJECTED BYY GOOGLE

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

If you are targeting Android 10 or newer (SDK level 29 or higher):
Remove the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission from your app APK or app bundle.
If you’re using ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, examine your code paths and restrict usage to foreground purposes only. (learn more)
Issue with your app
Since your app does not need background location, please request to remove background usage and reach compliance:

You should no longer see the Location declaration listed in console under App Content.
If your are targeting Android 9 or older (SDK level 28 or lower):
If you’re already using ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, examine your code paths and restrict usage to foreground purposes only. (learn more)
In your console declaration, select “No” to the question “Does your app access location in the background in APKs or app bundles targeting Android 9 or older?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check in your **AndroidManifest.xml** that Background permission exists or not, if it is there then remove it, and if it is not there so it means that some of your packages are using it. so you have to remove it manually like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
tools:node="remove"/>
```

Comment: Its important to add tools namespace to the XML manifiest: 

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="{PACKAGE_NAME}">

Answer (score 1):

i removed in my `AndroidManifest.xml` but some of my packages contains **android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** permission,

Solution for this,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
                 tools:node="remove"/>
```

above tools:node="remove" will remove from third party packages permissions

also add `xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"`  in your `<manifest>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file it should be like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" 
    package="yourpackagename">
```

Comment: This can be also be done with Android Studio by opening Merged Manifest tab when viewing the manifest and right-clicking the permission, which will then show option to remove it. But all in all, it will add the same lines as you've described here.

Answer (score 0):

it's good to add background location disclaimer alert to the user if click ok then start location in the background  if it's really crucial to the app functionality.otherwise , just delete  ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION from android manifest